# SSRS Visual studio report changing dates between file types

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

For a report I created, this one date column keeps changing between PDF and excel.

For example, in PDF it displays as '12/31/18' (which is the correct date) when I export the same report to excel, it displays as '1/1/2019'. It is displaying all dates as the actual value + 1 day.

Anyone know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your textbox properties where your date column is to a date format you like.

```
Textbox --> TextBox Properties --> Number
```

Choose category as Date and then your desired format. It should solve the problem.